# Applying JSON parsing to my case

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I've been following [this](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json-in-ios6/) tutorial. I was trying to apply it to my case. The JSON feed I'll be using is: [JSON feed](http://www.ah.nl/albertheijn/winkelinformatie/winkels).

They are using the following 'query':

```
 json[@"loans"][0][@"name"]
```

So I tried it for my case using:

```
json[@"0"][@"format"]
```

or

```
json[@"0"][0][@"format"]
```

but both are returning null.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, because what you have is not JSON. (I. e., it's "invalid" JSON - for example, it doesn't have dictionary keys surrounded by quotation marks, so the JSON parser, whatever you use, will presumably return `nil` because it can't parse it.)

By the way, even if it was valid JSON, neither of your approaches would have worked anyway. First you have an **array** as the root element, then its items are dictionaries. I. e., how you have to index is

```
json[0][@"format"]
```

(provided that `json` is an already parsed object, and not the JSON string itself!)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response! But then what is this feed giving me? And how will I be able to parse this?

Comment: @IvoVandeGrift If you don't have control over the contents of the feed, then you can use JavaScript only (or write your own parser for this invalid JSON). If you do have control over it, then just read the JSON specs and adjust the output accordingly.

Comment: No, it is not my feed. Could I change the acquired by adding `{"stores":` in front of it, and ending it with `}`?

Comment: @IvoVandeGrift No, the subobject would still be invalid non-JSON.

Comment: Ok, do you have a recommended way of how I might parse this then?

Comment: @IvoVandeGrift This is still valid JavaScript - if you can embed a lightweight JavaScript parser, that will do the trick. Or you can write your own parser as well.

Comment: I solved it. I edited the string on the page, so that it put quotes around the keys. Then I parsed the string using NSJSON....